# Downloading large files in Android - too much gc?

Tags: java, android

I have a class that extends Thread.

In it, my run() method has a while loop:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
input = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
output = new FileOutputStream(localFile, true);                                                             
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000); 
byte data[] = new byte[16384]; 

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

We are targeting ICS and above.  When we are downloading, we see a lot of Garbage Collection occuring in logcat.  It seems like a trivial method, is there something we're doing wrong here?  We're only creating the data array once.

Comment: How much GC is "a lot" of GC? Maybe attaching a portion of the logcat would help show the problem. There are different causes for initiating GC; what you're seeing may be entirely routine.

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: That code should produce roughly 0 GC. Once it is done `data[]` and the internal buffer of `BufferedInputStream` will be GC'd. Nothing should happen while the data is copied. You also don't need a `BufferedInputStream` if you buffer the data yourself.

Comment: Android's GC is slower than a desktops, so you'll see more time spent on garbage collection regaurdless. 

As @zapl says, this code doesn't seem to produce garbage. If you are seeing much GC its likely elsewhere. Try profiling your app with DDMS, and post your results. We'll be glad to help.

Comment: Do you have any other loops in your code?